# terminal vim colours broken on focuslost

Tags: 12.10, gnome-terminal, vim, vim-plugin

My `vim` setup uses the `csexact` plugin to fix match the colors for color schemes that would normally only work in `gvim`. Everything works fine until `gnome-terminal` loses focus, and suddenly everything breaks!

Here is an image of issue in action:
[image: The issue]

I have the exact same `vim` setup on my laptop (ubuntu 12.04 32bit, gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1, vim compiled from source). However, on my PC (ubuntu 12.10 64bit, gnome-terminal 3.6.0, vim compiled from source), this issue occurs. I hesitate to blame the `csexact` plugin, since `vim` in `gnome-terminal` cannot receive `focuslost` or `focusgained` events, this must be a `terminal` issue then; however I do notice that when the colors break if I run `:CSExactColors`  everything fixes again.

What can I do? Any ideas on how to fix this, what the issue is, or even a workaround? Thanks

Comment: I've compiled and run gnome terminal 3.4.1.1, and find the same issue occurring. With that I'm not even sure what this error could be associated with, or how I can even look into where things are going wrong

Comment: Hey guys, I wasn't able to properly fix this, however I started using [link](https://launchpad.net/sakura) instead and now I get proper colours without that gross colour change

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in vte, which was fixed a while ago (in 0.36 if I recall correctly).